# Power BI - count grouped values with condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to Power BI and struggling to work out the following.In excel i would have used a COUNTIF. I have a table:

```
+-----+----------+
| ID  | Status   |
+-----+----------+
| 1   | Complete |
+-----+----------+
| 2   | Started  |
+-----+----------+
| 3   | Started  |
+-----+----------+
| 1   | Complete |
+-----+----------+
| 1   | Complete |
+-----+----------+
```

I would like to summarize the data and count the number of `complete` jobs, grouped by `ID`. The output i would like is :

```
+-----+----------+-------+
|  ID | Status   | Count |
+-----+----------+-------+
| 1   | Complete | 3     |
+-----+----------+-------+
| 2   | Started  | 1     |
+-----+----------+-------+
| 3   | Started  | 1     |
+-----+----------+-------+
| 1   | Complete | 3     |
+-----+----------+-------+
| 1   | Complete | 3     |
+-----+----------+-------+
```

Which i would then like to keep only distinct values where the count is greater than 2 (is this possible without the intermediate step above? ). So my final desired result is:

```
+-----+----------+-------+
| ID  | Status   | Count |
+-----+----------+-------+
| 1   | Complete | 3     |
+-----+----------+-------+
```

I have tried:

```
 Unique =  COUNTAX(FILTER(Sheet1,(Sheet1[Status] = "Complete" && (Sheet1[Status] = EARLIER(Sheet1[Status])))),Sheet1[Status])
```

but this gives me a running total and not the count.

What formula do i need to use please?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for the count of records per ID, with status as complete. It can be achieved using `ALLEXCEPT`. The following calculation will give you the desire count at ID level:

```
Count = CALCULATE(COUNT(Sheet1[ID]),ALLEXCEPT(Sheet1,Sheet1[ID]),Sheet1[Status]="Complete")
```

Once your field is created, you can apply a filter in the column to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks @CR7SMS - this answered my question :)

Comment: How would i modify the formula to filter the data? I can do so by dragging the field onto the filter section in power bi, but how would i do it using the formula? cheers

Comment: In the above formula Sheet1[Status]="Complete" is the filter part. If you want additional filters you can add it in the same format after the first filter.

Comment: Would this filter the column? What i mean is, this formula is creating a column with various numerical values, and the column itself is called count. Im trying to now filter the column to only include all values that are more than 2.

Comment: if you want to filter your entire data based on the calculated field, then you have to apply this as a filter in the filter pane

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table visual with `ID` and `Status` as columns, then you can write a simple measure `Count` as follows:

```
Count =
VAR Complete =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Sheet1[ID] ),
        FILTER ( Sheet1, Sheet1[Status] = "Complete" )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( Complete >= 2, Complete ) /*False returns BLANK()*/
```